# How i can stop SQL server 2008 Express from Startup in Windows ?

Tags: database, sql-server-2008

i am installing SQL server 2008 express and found that many exe run on startup even i not used them.

can i stop them or allow to run them only after when i want to run them. means when i want only that time those run otherwise not.

how i can remove them from startup

Comment: What version of Windows is this on ? Generally from XP onwards you can type services.msc in Start -> Run and disable these services. Open each one and change start up from Automatic to Disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see all your SQL server instances from the Sql Server Configuration Manager if you have it. There you can set the startmode to Manual instead of Automatic. This can also be done from the services console as arunkumar said. The service should be named SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS).

Comment: i already set all to manual but nothing i feel that's it's stop next time i can see them.

Comment: In the Sql Server Configuration Manager (or Services), right click the instance and click stop. I was able to stop all process that had anything to do with SQL server (as far as i know). I had to stop the VSS writer service (sqlwriter.exe) from services.msc.

Answer (score 0):

As @arunkumar said, you can change the services to disabled, or you can set them to Automatic also, but that may not change much. Generally, SQL Server is usually the main purpose of the PC, so it thinks it always needs to run :)

Answer (score 0):

First thing will be to setup all those SQL Server and related services to run "Manually" instead of "Automatic" using Sql Server Configuration Manager.

I usually create two batch files, one to start SQL Server and related services like `net start MSSQLSERVER` and another to stop SQL Server when I am not using it like `net stop MSSQLSERVER`.
Of course there will be other related services as well.

If you can't stop services as you indicated in one of your reply, then may be you don't have enough privileges to perform that operation ??

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
run CMD "Run as Administrator" 
command STOP
net stop mssql$express ,
command START
net start mssql$express
```